# Scroll to specific slide when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel

I want to assign a button to each slide in the carousel so when clicked it would scroll to the specific slide.

Nuka-carousel documentation doesn't explain much about it so I tried this but it didn't work.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Carousel from "nuka-carousel";

const Carousel = () => {

const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);

  const sliderRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSlideChange = (swiper) => {
    setActiveSlide(swiper.realIndex);
  };

  const handleSlideButtonClick = (index) => {
    if (sliderRef.current) {
      sliderRef.current.swiper.slideTo(index);
      setActiveSlide(index);
    }
  };

  return (
                 <Carousel
                  ref={sliderRef}
                  onChange={handleSlideChange}
                  slideIndex="0"
                  cellAlign="center"
                  slidesToShow={2}
                  className="carousel"
                  speed={900}
                  >
                  <IntroScreen />
                  <SuccessScreen />
                  <PaymentScreen />
                  <PrintScreen />
                 </Carousel>

                 <div>
                   <button onClick={() => handleSlideButtonClick(0)}>1<button>
                   <button onClick={() => handleSlideButtonClick(1)}>2<button>
                   <button onClick={() => handleSlideButtonClick(2)}>3<button>
                   <button onClick={() => handleSlideButtonClick(3)}>4<button>
                  </div>
)
}

export default Carousel
```